# rm -rf written in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'd like to achieve `rm -rf` or a directory and all of it's contents with the minimum amount of code possible.

I've only found scripts with around 50 lines or more of code, there must be a less than 10 line code snippet for this?

There are two ways of doing this, pure Node.js or using spawn/exec to use the `rm -rf` command.

`rm -rf` way:

```
function spawnCustom(command, options) {
    const array = command.split(' ');
    const first_command = array[0];
    array.shift();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

        const child = spawn(first_command, array, options);
        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            process.stdout.write('stdout: ' + data);
            // Here is where the output goes
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            process.stdout.write('stderr: ' + data);
            // Here is where the error output goes
            reject(data);
        });
        child.on('close', function(code) {
            process.stdout.write('closing code: ' + code);
            // Here you can get the exit code of the script
            resolve();
        });
    }); 
}

await spawnCustom('rm -rf ~/example_dir');
```

`Node.js` way:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

let _dirloc = '<path_do_the_directory>'

if (existsSync(_dirloc)) {
    fs.readdir(path, (error, files) => {
        if(!error) {
            for(let file of files) {
                // Delete each file
                fs.unlinkSync(path.join(_dirloc,file))
            }
        }
    })

    // After the done of each file delete,
    // Delete the directory itself
    if(fs.unlinkSync(_dirloc)) {
        console.log('Directory has been deleted!')
    }
}
```

A lot of code for something simple.. There must be a more simple way?

Comment: if you don't mind using external library to do this, try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/del

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Available (experimentally) since Node v12.10

As per the NodeJS v14.0.0 docs this feature has been available since v12.10.0 but is marked experimental.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmdir_path_options_callback

### Async

```js
const fs = require('fs');

(async function() {
  const cleanup_result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.rmdir("./temp", {recursive: true}, (err) => resolve(err));
  });

  console.log(`Cleaned up data with result "${JSON.stringify(cleanup_result)}"`);
)();
```

### Promisified Async

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const rmdir = util.promisify(fs.rmdir);

(async function() {
  const cleanup_result = await rmdir("./temp", {recursive: true});
)();
```

### Sync

```js
const fs = require('fs');
// Process blocking action which can halt 
// your program if deleting a large directory tree
fs.rmdirSync("./temp", {recursive: true});
```

Answer (score 5):

That would be the [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) module.

Can be done in 2 lines

```
 var rimraf = require('rimraf');
 rimraf('/some/directory', () => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: I did notice this library! I think there should be a util in node.js's util library though that should fix this :(

Answer (score 0):

There were moments that I also thought: I *really* wish there was a function to easily delete a directory recursively. I could talk about this for hours ("what makes a language 'complete' enough") but I think that would be out of the scope for stackoverflow.

To answer your question: first of all, your first example is an overkill! I would just use `exec` since the output will be very small. You could rewrite it way shorter:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const deleteDir = (dir) => {
    exec(`test -d ${dir} && rm -rf ${dir}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
deleteDir('example-dir');
```

In this example `test -d` checks for the existence of the directory and returns exit code `0` on success or `1` on failure (which will never trigger the the right part of the `&&`.

But the thing is: if you're writing code for a larger public, you would like to support, for example, other operating systems. Packages like `rimraf` will take care of that for you! [Look at its source code](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) and especially the test cases.

Of course you can write it yourself, but I think because so many people use rimraf, all kinds of weird exceptions have been noticed and fixes has been committed etc.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do this is with `fs.rm({ recursive: true })`. See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmpath-options-callback) on this.